# Using an API to create data in a ReactTable

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js and want to use this API here: https://atlas.api.barclays/open-banking/v2.2/branches to create a table with Barclays branches data. My problem is, when I render the app, I can't seem to upload the data into the table, only the column's headers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

````
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactTable from "react-table-6"; 
import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      branches: [],
      loading:true
    }
  }
  async getBranchesData(){
    const data = await axios.get('https://atlas.api.barclays/open-banking/v2.2/branches')
    console.log(data.Branch)
    this.setState({loading:false, branches: data.Branch})
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getBranchesData()
  }
  render() {
    const columns = [
      {  
      Header: 'Identification',  
      accessor: 'Identification',
     }
     ,{  
      Header: 'Sequence Number',  
      accessor: 'SequenceNumber' ,
      }
     
     ,{  
     Header: 'Name',  
     accessor: 'Name' ,
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Type',  
     accessor: 'Type',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Photo',  
     accessor: 'Photo',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Customer Segment',  
     accessor: 'CustomerSegment',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Service and Facility',  
     accessor: 'ServiceAndFacility',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Accessibility',  
     accessor: 'Accessibility',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Other Accessibility',  
     accessor: 'OtherAccessibility',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Other Service and Facility',  
     accessor: 'OtherServiceAndFacility',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Availability',  
     accessor: 'Availability',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Contact Info',  
     accessor: 'ContactInfo',
     }
     ,{  
     Header: 'Postal Address',  
     accessor: 'PostalAddress',
     }
  ]
    return (
     <ReactTable  
      data={this.state.branches}  
      columns={columns} />
    )
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

change the next line:

**`this.setState({loading:false, branches: data.Branch})`**

for this:

**`this.setState({loading:false, branches: data.Brand.Branch})`**

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed it and I got this error.. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Branch')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you're using the React Table library. It only provides table utilities and not a table component as you're trying to use. You can check this [basic usage example](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic) in their docs to try to fit your use case.

You can use HTML table elements or any UI component libraries (such as [Bootstrap](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/bootstrap-ui-components) or [Material UI](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/material-ui-components)) to render your table, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the response of the api.

```
const response = {
    meta: {},
    data: [
        {
            "Brand": [
                {
                    "BrandName": "Barclays UK",
                    "Branch": [
                        {
                            "Identification": "UK-B-20533008",
                            // etc
                        },
                        {
                            "Identification": "UK-B-20533008",
                            // etc
                        },
                        // etc
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I think you want data.data[0].Brand[0].Branch.